# ASP .NET Core Cookie Authentication expiration changes from timestamp to "Session" upon return

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP .NET Core RC1 with Facebook-authentication and silding window cookie expiration set up like this:

```
app.UseIdentity();
app.UseFacebookAuthentication();
```

and

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>((options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "myauthcookie";
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
}))
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This works fine when the user first logs in - the cookie expiration is set correctly. However, when the user returns to the page, the expiration of the cookie is set to "Session", so in practice the user has to re-authenticate every other visit.

Why is this happening? Have I not configured it correctly?

**Update**:
I have now done some testing without SlidingExpiration, and the issue remains the same. Upon returning to the page, the expiration of the cookie is changed to "Session". I am using Chrome.

Also, I am not running on https. Might this be a factor?

Comment: the facebook cookie is a different cookie, you probably need to set it similar to the main applicationcookie, look at options.Cookies.External...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. But then why is the expiration date of my auth cookie set correctly in the first place? I log in with Facebook every time

Comment: ultimately you get an application cookie and it should work as configured, I'm just guessing there might be some interplay logic with the external cookie that you also get as part of the facebook process so setting it with similar settings might be needed, I'm just spit balling if I were sure I would post as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer

Set `isPersistent: true` when calling `SignInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync`.

## Details

In the ASP.NET Core Web Application template, the `AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback` method contains this code:

```
_signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(
    info.LoginProvider, 
    info.ProviderKey, 
    isPersistent: true);     <------ set a persistent cookie.
```

If we set `isPersistent: true` when calling `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` , this startup configuration...

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "MyApplicationCookie";
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

...results in this application cookie...

[image: MyApplicationCookie is persistent.]

...which persists across browser sessions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Shaun. Allthough I didn't specify it in my question, I am already setting ´isPersistent: true´ in my call to the SignInManager, so the code I am running is in fact exactly what you posted, which explains why the cookie is set correctly at the first login.
My issue is that on some returning visit, "Expires on" is overwritten and set to "Session".

Comment: @fiskeboss That's odd. I am not experiencing the same behavior. Could please please try with `options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` and refresh the page every five seconds to see what happens with your cookie. For me the refresh every five seconds pushes the expiration by another ten seconds. What happens with you?

Comment: Also, on what web browser are you experiencing this?

Comment: When trying to set the ExpireTimeSpan to anything under 2 hours, the cookie is not set at all, so I can't even log in. Also odd.

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @fiskeboss. That is not the behavior that I am seeing in Chrome. Hmm. We have a mystery on our hands. Cool!

Comment: I just did some more experimenting, and I still get the same results. The threshold for ExpireTimeSpan for when the cookie gets stored is exactly 2 hours. This happens both with Facebook-login and with normal built-in user accounts. Disabling SlidingExpiration doesn't help either. I did the tests on my local development machine.